# How can I db.collection.count() over the same query with different conditions?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Can I use single query instead of multiple count queries to get the counts for the three ranges below?

```
db.ARTDocument.count({'latestResult.boostedResult.relevancy': {$lt:40}})
db.ARTDocument.count({'latestResult.boostedResult.relevancy': {$gt:40,$lt:60}})
db.ARTDocument.count({'latestResult.boostedResult.relevancy': {$gt:60}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want just one query, you can call [`db.eval()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/) (make sure that performance requirements are met). In the eval, you run `db.find()` to find practically all records (I've added an `$exist` test just in case. Then you check for each record where it falls in the `< 40 < 60` range. Something like this:

```
db.eval(function() {
    var lt40 = 0, gt40lt60 = 0, gt60 = 0, r;
    db.ARTDocument.find({'latestResult.boostedResult.relevancy': {$exists:1}}).forEach(function(doc) {
        r = doc.latestResult.boostedResult.relevancy;
        if (r < 40) {
            lt40 ++;
        } else {
            r < 60 ? gt40lt60++ : gt60++
        }    
    });
    return {
        lt40: lt40,
        gt40lt60: gt40lt60,
        gt60: gt60
    }    
});
```

Finally, you return a record with the three counts.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Query is working as expected but is there any other approach which uses aggregate function and does not impact performance

Answer (score 1):

Possible to mapReduce isn't it?
I suspect this will be better than a db.eval as it will utilise shards properly.

```
mapper=function(){
    if (this.latestResult.boostedResult.relevancy >40){
        emit('lt40', {'count':1});
    }
    if (this.latestResult.boostedResult.relevancy > 40 && this.latestResult.boostedResult.relevancy<60){
        emit('middle', {'count':1});
    }
    if (this.latestResult.boostedResult.relevancy >60){
        emit('gt60', {'count':1});
    }
}


reducer=function(k,v){
    counter=0;
    for (i=0;i<v.length;i++){
        counter+=v[i].count;
    }
    return {'count':counter}
}
db.ArtCategories.mapReduce(mapper, reducer, {out:{inline:1}})
```

This should give you the results broken down into the categories

Comment: This solution may be better than mine. Let the benchmarks decide!

Answer (score 0):

Can we consider this instead of mapReduce?

```
db.ARTDocument.aggregate([
{"$group": {
  "_id": {"$cond": [
      {"$lte": ["$latestResult.boostedResult.relevancy", 40] },
      "Lowest",                                  
      {"$cond": [
          {"$and": [
              {"$gt": ["$latestResult.boostedResult.relevancy", 40] },
              {"$lte": ["$latestResult.boostedResult.relevancy", 60] }
          ]},
          "Medium",
         {"$cond": [
             {"$and": [
                 {"$gt": ["$latestResult.boostedResult.relevancy", 60] },
                 {"$lte": ["$latestResult.boostedResult.relevancy", 80 ] }
             ]},
             "Higher",
               "Highest"
         ]}
     ]}
 ]},
 "count": {"$sum": 1}
   }},
   {"$sort": { "count": 1 }}
])
```